# need help to generate keystrokes into existing application in Linux environment using C++

Tags: c++, linux

I need help to generate keystrokes in my existing application in LINUX environment.
I am fully aware that there are libraries in Dev C++ which do exactly what I want but in Windows and I need something like that in Linux. I have googled a lot, but could  not able to find any solution.
Below are the code of Dev C++ library and I want something like that in Linux. Any help, suggestion , criticism are most welcome.

```
void GenerateKey(int vk , BOOL bExtended)  
{  
  KEYBDINPUT kb = {0};  
  INPUT Input = {0};  

  // generate down   
  if(bExtended)  
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;  
  kb.wVk = vk;     

  Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  
  Input.ki = kb;  
  ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));  
  // generate up    
  ::ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));  
  ::ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));  

  kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;  
  if(bExtended)   
    kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;  

  kb.wVk = vk;  
  Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  
  Input.ki = kb;  
  ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));  
}
```

Thanks and regards,
SamPrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is create and initialize `XKeyEvent` struct and send it with `XSendEvent`.

Be sure to check `man xkeyevent` and `man xsendevent`

From `man xkeyevent`:

```
   typedef struct {
        int type;                /* KeyPress or KeyRelease */
        unsigned long serial;    /* # of last request processed by server */
        Bool send_event;         /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
        Display *display;        /* Display the event was read from */
        Window window;           /* ``event'' window it is reported relative to */
        Window root;             /* root window that the event occurred on */
        Window subwindow;        /* child window */
        Time time;               /* milliseconds */
        int x, y;                /* pointer x, y coordinates in event window */
        int x_root, y_root;      /* coordinates relative to root */
        unsigned int state;      /* key or button mask */
        unsigned int keycode;    /* detail */
        Bool same_screen;        /* same screen flag */
   } XKeyEvent;
```

To get key keycodes, check `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` ur just use `xev`

I found a [brief introduction](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/events.html) for you.

(Edit: It seems [someone solved it](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html) already :))

Comment: Thanks Palmik,  for such a quick reply,  I will look into it. Seem it will solve my problem.Thanks a lot

Comment: Dear PalmiK, The code compiles properly, but I am wondering how would I test it to check if its doing I or not.

Comment: Will this work in Linux systems which doesn't start Xserver ?