# Keyboard.print() equivalent for C on Teensy?

Tags: c, arduino, teensy

I'm trying to write a program for Teensy that uses it as a keyboard. I want it to print out certain strings depending on input, but some of the strings are rather long. I know that for Arduino IDE there's a simple `Keyboard.print()` function that allows the sending of strings. Does this functionality exist for C as well?

Comment: Start with a good C book.

Comment: @Olaf what does that mean? Besides the obvious... I mean, I can call it a char array if you want :)

Comment: Just start reading. YOu willfind your question answered there. If I would tell you now what to use, this will lead to quite some follow-up questions. So it's better you start learnig yourself. Teaching fishing vs. giving a fish.

Comment: @Olaf I'm guessing that's a "no." That's OK, I can write it myself. I was just hoping to be a bit more memory-efficient.

Comment: Which Teensy version? Teensy++ 2.0 and earlier are AVRs and can be programmed using avr-gcc on bare metal or in Arduino IDE using [teensyduino](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensyduino.html); Teensy 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and LC have ARM cores and all the support libraries require using the Arduino IDE. Remember, Arduino sketches are just C++ with a bit of automatic source massaging thrown in; you can just write C++ in Arduino IDE, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, so I've answered both interpretations I got from it.

### If you are referring to using a Teensy as an input device.

Yes, this should be possible with all Teensy units if you use [teensyduino](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensyduino.html) under the OS of your choice. Simply put in your code and set the [Teensy as a HID device](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_keyboard.html) to use it.
To restate good advice, be careful testing as a rogue keyboard can quickly cause a lot of trouble for you.

### If you are referring to getting a C program to emulate a keyboard.

Yes, this is also possible.

**Linux Instructions**

[Example Code](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html) - [Found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4427801/4541045)
The example uses `#define KEYCODE XK_Down`, which is "safe", but can be hard to show. Try adding `#define KEYCODE XK_A`, `#include <unistd.h>`, and `usleep(2000000); // 2 seconds` in appropriate places to control the behavior.
Additionally, if you need C instead of C++, change `Window &win` to `Window win` in `createKeyEvent`

Modified code below `XFakeKey.c`

```
// Send a fake keystroke event to an X window.
// by Adam Pierce - http://www.doctort.org/adam/
// This is public domain software. It is free to use by anyone for any purpose.

// debug message, delay, and conversion to C by ti7
// original code found at http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

// The key code to be sent.
// A full list of available codes can be found in /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
//#define KEYCODE XK_Down
#define KEYCODE XK_A

// Function to create a keyboard event
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window win,
                           Window winRoot, int press,
                           int keycode, int modifiers)
{
   XKeyEvent event;

   event.display     = display;
   event.window      = win;
   event.root        = winRoot;
   event.subwindow   = None;
   event.time        = CurrentTime;
   event.x           = 1;
   event.y           = 1;
   event.x_root      = 1;
   event.y_root      = 1;
   event.same_screen = True;
   event.keycode     = XKeysymToKeycode(display, keycode);
   event.state       = modifiers;

   if(press)
      event.type = KeyPress;
   else
      event.type = KeyRelease;

   return event;
}

#define true 1
#define false 0

#include <stdio.h> // for printf
#include <unistd.h> // for time
main()
{
// Obtain the X11 display.
   Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
   if(display == NULL)
      return -1;
    printf("it's working\n");
// Get the root window for the current display.
   Window winRoot = XDefaultRootWindow(display);

    usleep(1000000);
// Find the window which has the current keyboard focus.
   Window winFocus;
   int    revert;
   XGetInputFocus(display, &winFocus, &revert);

// Send a fake key press event to the window.
   XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, true, KEYCODE, 0);
   XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Send a fake key release event to the window.
   event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, KEYCODE, 0);
   XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

// Done.
   XCloseDisplay(display);
   return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -o XFakeKey XFakeKey.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11`

**Windows Example**

[Example Code](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/)
I'm feeling brave and have not tested this, so hold on to your pants.